# Can't display image from API call React Js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, src

I'm trying to display images from API call, response.json() returns img sources as

```
{"imgSrc":"/rimg/source/cars/v/1.jpg?crop=false&width=55&height=92&fallback=default3.png&_v=45788f99e6dcc"

}
```

and when I use it as src, images are broken and are not displayed. Any help and advice is greatly appreciated.

Comment: It seems like you're receiving a local path to an image and the requested image cannot be found at that location. Can you post any further information or code snippets

Comment: How are you sending and receiving the images? Please add some code to help us understand your use case

Answer (score 0):

This is because the images locations returned are relative. You have 2 possible solutions:

- Either you make your server return the complete address of the images (with the server's address/domain name)
- Or you just add it to the response in the frontend

Both should make the returned locations absolute (with the server's address/domain name on it). Thus, the images locations should look like this:

```
{"imgSrc":"https://myServer.com/rimg/source/cars/v/1.jpg?crop=false&width=55&height=92&fallback=default3.png&_v=45788f99e6dcc"}
```